# No hint path defined for [pagination]. Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, pagination, laravel-5.3

I'm receiving this error on pagination, and reset password post request on Laravel 5.3. Trying to figure out what's causing since I can see that error happens on `FileViewFinder.php` line 112, which contains:

```
if (! isset($this->hints[$segments[0]])) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("No hint path defined for   [{$segments[0]}].");
    }
```

This code is part of the `getNamespaceSegment($name)` method, which gets the segment of a template with a named path. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I figured out, what was happening. Basically the message says FileViewFinder cannot find the related templates that are required when pagination function is called:

```
$paginator->links();
```

So the solution is to first make sure the files are published by running:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination
```

And then update path to the pagination templates located in `resources/views/vendor/pagination`:

```
$paginator->links('vendor.pagination.default')
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have error into your blade file, define the default pagination file

```
$paginator -> links('vendor.pagination.default')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set it manually

if you have your blades views in ...views/pagination, that is how you can specify it:

```
app('pagination')->addNamespace('mail', resource_path('views') . '/pagination');
```